# Kali Linux Debian /dev/sda1 low disk space after the installation

Tags: debian, kali-linux, system-installation, hard-disk

After I installed Kali Linux in Virtual Box, I tried installing the Guest Additions. After I ran this command:

```
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I got a message that I had low disk space.

How do I free up disk space or remove the Linux additions?

I have a 13GM hard disk, and I only have 1GB free space. Mind you, this is after the installation so I didn't download anything.

The output for

```
df -h
```

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that this picture is from your VM, correct? What do you mean by `installing Guest Additions on Debian`?

Comment: Yes this is a VM.I wanted to have a full-screen option so I installed a Guest Additions